# How to prepare a list of functions for Future.wait?

Tags: dart

I want to prepare a list of functions for `Future.wait` beforehand so that I can run them all later. After some research I came up with the following:

```
Future<void> _processData(String name) async {
(...)
}

List<Future<void> Function()> futures = [];

for (var m in data) {
futures.add(_processData(m.name)); 
}

Future.wait(futures);
```

However it comes back with `The argument type 'Future<void>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<void> Function()'` on the `futures.add` line.

I thought I could skip the `Function()` in the definition of the `futures` list to match types, but then it would call all these functions right away when adding. How else would I make a list of functions like the above without calling them until `Future.wait`?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because in this line: `futures.add(_processData(m.name))` you are invoking the function _processData, thereby trying to add the return value, which is of type Future. How about the following?

```
Future.wait(data.map((m) => _processData(m.name)).toList());
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed my version is trying to call the functions and add return values. However it's not that clear to me why would the code in your example still not try to do the same thing. Would you care to explain the rationale? Won't it also say 'for each (m) run _processData(m.name) and get the return value' ?

Comment: My code would invoke the functions too, but this time we are generating the list at the time of Future.wait, where we want to invoke it. Technically, we don't have a pre-populated list of Future-returning functions, like you wanted. Instead, we are generating that list right when we want to call them.

Comment: Makes sense. However, the above is kinda simplified version of the code. Long story short there's some things that need to happen in between (e.g. I'm dividing the data into batches because the API I'm calling will only allow a certain number of requests a second), and then delaying multiple Future.waits to be called on these batches. - hence it would be nice to process, clean and preload the batches before the whole process starts. Well still if there's no way to dynamically prepare a list of functions this way in Dart then I guess I can use your example and process things within each call..

Answer (score 0):

Your `futures` list is declared to be a `List` of (zero-argument) *functions* that return `Future`s.  Therefore, either:

- Give it a list of functions:

  ```dart
  List<Future<void> Function()> futures = [];
  for (var m in data) {
    futures.add(() => _processData(m.name)); 
  }
  ```

  or more directly:

  ```dart
  List<Future<void> Function()> futures = [
    for (var m in data) () => _processData(m.name)),
  ];
  ```

  and then do:

  ```dart
  await Future.wait([
    for (var function in futures) function(),
  ]);
  ```
- Or give it a list of `Future`s instead of functions:

  ```dart
  var futures = [
    for (var m in data) _processData(m.name),
  ];
  await Future.wait(futures);
  ```

I would just do the latter since there isn't much point to adding an extra level of function calls.  In both cases, each iteration ultimately would invoke `_processData` and wait for it to yield (`await` or `return`) before proceeding to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* call the functions immediately, and change the list type to `List<Future<void>>`.

The point with asynchronous functions is that you call them now, but they complete with a result later, through the `Future`.
The `Future.wait` function doesn't call functions, it just waits for futures that have already been created.

I'd probably write it shorter as:

```dart
await Future.wait([for (var m in data) _processData(m.name)]);
```

but what you are doing is also OK, if the list is a list of futures.

Comment: Can this be done with forEach? So yes, how? If not; why?

Comment: Probably not, depending on what "this" is. Why do you ask?